# Mongoid Query By Referenced Document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

What is mongoid/ruby syntax for:

I would like to query for a `Parent` including all `Children` (eagerly) searching by some unique `Child` attribute (not the `_id`).

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, :type => String
  field :last_name, :type => String

  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Child', :inverse_of => :parent
end

class Child
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, :type => String
  field :last_name, :type => String

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Parent', :inverse_of => :children
end
```

in SQL, I would write

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM   Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c
ON     c.parent_id = p._id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Child c2 WHERE c2.first_name = 'Aaron' AND c2.parent_id = p._id
);
```

Comment: mongoid which version you are using?

Comment: mongoid version 3.0.23

Comment: should I even bother trying to create one query?  My mindset has always been to cut down on the number of database requests, but I guess I can live with, `c = Child.find_by(:first_name => 'Aaron'); p = Parent.includes(:children).find(c.parent_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
children = Child.where(:first_name => "Aaron")
children.each do |child|
   parent = child.parent
end
```

if you need only publication details based on above condition you can run this

```
Parent.includes(:child).where('child.first_name' => "Aaron")
```

but for children you have to again make the query.